# Cann't recovery on my hard disk recovery partition

Tags: windows-7

I cann't recover my windows 7 32 bit from the recovery partition and it was displayed status : 0xc0000225
Windows 7 32bit- Error 0xc0000225 on boot

Comment: Is it not booting in safe mode too? Why you got this problem may be helpful to tell us. Also what have you already tried?

Comment: More information please.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to have a recovery CD/DVD/USB Drive.  I have also just being fed up at the recovery drive never working right, and just reinstalled Windows on top of the current one as it let me keep personal files.  A side benefit is no malware and a faster bootspeed.  There is also no bloatware.

Here is some advise from Microsoft Answers, good luck!

[MS Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/error-0xc0000225-windows-does-not-start-up/c662ce05-3905-4fce-a2be-70688812d9f5)